# Javascript and using an MVC style model (with angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object I want to use as a model for my angular controller.

```
var SchedulingModel = function() {
    this.weekdays = Weekdays;
    this.scheduleType = "2";
    this.customerType = "1";
    this.timesOfTheMonth = TimesOfTheMonth;
    this.waivers = [];
}
```

angular controller:

```
$scope.model = SchedulingModel;
```

When I try and access model.weekdays and model.timesOfTheMonth they are both undefined...

```
console.log($scope.model.timesOfTheMonth);
console.log($scope.model.weekdays);
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do new of SchedulingModel

```
$scope.model = new SchedulingModel();
```

Comment: As a new JS developer, I thought it was unusual that I was able to assign the objects without instantiating instances of them

Answer (score 1):

In that case it is not angular thing. Please try:

```
console.log(SchedulingModel.weekdays) //undefined
// but this will work
var TimesOfTheMonth = '';
var Weekdays = "";
var a = new SchedulingModel();
console.log(a.weekdays); //works ok
```